# Represent user's reputation and type by a special character in the display name

Tags: feature-request, privileges, reputation-display

What I know is that based on reputation, users get privileges e.g. the ability to see deleted posts, voting for flagged messages, reviews etc.

I noticed that moderator's display name has a `Diamond` representing that this is Moderator:

> [image]

Same way I suggest that there should be some other symbol which represent user's reputation e.g. more than 10K, 15k, 20k etc.

Further also want to know how many types of users exist and their roles, responsibility, access etc. I know about normal users and moderators, Any others?

Comment: There are also developers, but you can't recognize them. Some have diamonds, some not.

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe: Correct for e.g. [mythz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/85785/mythz)

Comment: There are also unregistered users; they have Unregistered next to their name. Other than that I don't see the point of having flair next to a user that represents their 10k status when you can just look at their reputation score in their user card or profile, unless you're that bad at counting...

Comment: Avatar is the image, you mean display name. I've corrected the post for you making it more clear what you really asked for.

Comment: Thanks, @ShaWizDowArd exactly I meant the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I disagree. In questions and answers, you can always see the user's reputation in his usercart. In comments, you can hover your mouse over the user's name to see his reputation score. Thus, I don't think any further indication of the user's reputation is needed.

[image][image]

Other than normal users and the moderators, there aren't any "special" roles really, unless you count [high-rep privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) as "roles". Well, of course there also are StackExchange developers, but I think they usually have a moderator diamond too (though it's up to them whether they want to have a diamond or not).